# my alert dialogue is not working?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am new to android development field, so tried for an `AlertDialog` box and i having trouble with it.
Here is my section code for `AlertDialog`.

```
public void teacherLogin(View view)
{

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new 
    AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    alert.setTitle("Login");
    alert.setPositiveButton("Login", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you clicked login", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancelled", 
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.show();
}
```

And here is my xml code for `Button` that invoked teacherLogin() method

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/teacher_loginbtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:onClick="teacherLogin"
    android:text="Teacher's Login"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="22dp" />
```

Comment: try changing getApplicationContext() to YourActivity.this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this my friend

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Comment: Simple and straightforward. Just tried this and it works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you for your note!

Answer (score 3):

Try changing getApplicationContext()to YourActivity.this

```
public void teacherLogin(View view)
{

AlertDialog.Builder alert = new 
AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
alert.setTitle("Login");
alert.setPositiveButton("Login", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "you clicked login", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Cancelled", 
       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
dialog.show();
 }
```